# Multiple image upload with remove and preview Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, file-upload

I searched on internet for like 3 days looking for good solution on displaying uploaded images and removing them before submit, but none of the packages didn't work on my Laravel project.

I even tried making dynamic input file.The biggest problem was that every time user uploads file, old entries were lost in process, only files from last 'session' were stored.

Does anyone know what is the best and easiest solution for this problem?

Comment: use this https://pqina.nl/filepond/

Comment: "old entries were lost in process, only files from last 'session' were stored" We can know that unless code is shown in question. Focus on one issue at time. [How to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader

**BUT** is not a Cross Browser solution.

It works in Google Chrome, and in safari, for example, does not work.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.